# Regex to match look before this or that

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm attempting to match the inside of a url.

`www.facebook.com` `http://www.facebook.com` `http://facebook.com`

should return `facebook`

My current regex is `(?<=www\.|http:\/\/).*(?=\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})`

this matches all correctly except for the one with `http://www.`, the match for this is `www.facebook`

How would I make the regex look before to match the last occurrence of either `www`or`http://`

[Rubular Link](http://rubular.com/r/pY5nGusCwI)

Comment: Why you are trying to use a lookbehind instead of using a basic grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, you can use this:

```
(?i)^(?:http://)?(?:\w+\.)?\K\w+(?=\.[a-z]{2,4}$)
```

See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vF8eZ1).

- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?i)` puts us in case-insensitive mode
- `(?:http://)?` optionally matches the `http://` part
- `(?:\w+\.)?` optionally matches a subdomain
- `\K` Keeps Out what we have matched from the match to be returned
- `\w+` matches `facebook`
- The `(?=\.[a-z]{2,4}$)` lookahead checks that it is followed by a domain then the end of the string.

Comment: FYI added demo and explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

In python, I solved the problem using sub from re:

```
from re import sub
x = "http://www.facebook.com" #hypothetical website
y = sub("(.*www\.|http:\/\/)(.*)\.com","\\2",x) 
print y
```

outputs **"facebook"**

Hope this translates to Ruby and helps!